# Later change of taxonomy slug base not changing permalink

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, slug

When defining a taxonomy I successfully set the slug base for it as well, all via functions.php. However, any change on the slug’s base (via editing functions.php again) is being recognised, i.e. it links to the right new URL, but lead to a 404. The term is still to be found at the original URL. More concrete:

1. For the taxonomy slug definition I use `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'countries' )` in my functions.php.
2. The URL of a term is then e.g. `www.xxx.com/countries/england`
3. I change the slug to `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'regions' )`.
4. Frontend now links to `www.xxx.com/regions/england`, but produces a 404 – the term can still be found at www.xxx.com/countries/england.

Is there a way to savely edit and change the slug sitewide or is it a bug of sorts in WordPress? I tried `flush_rewrite_rules();` in my functions.php after initialisation of the taxonomy, but still no luck.

Comment: Normal flushing the permalinks should fix it, IDK why it's not working for you, do you see a .htaccess file?

Comment: Is `flush_rewrite_rules();` actually needed (I know, not permanently) when I hit the permalink options page anyway? In any way, there is a .htaccess file, yes, and working normally. So it should work out of the box when I already have created terms and posts for it, for the existing terms and posts as well?

Answer (score 0):

Physalis, reset the permalinks from setting, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As user9279 suggested (albeit a bit hard to understand), go to your Settings -> Permalinks and save them again. This tends to fix issues like this (as well as, for example, a 404 when viewing a newly created custom post type).

If this doesn't work, I suggest you look at the order of the registration for the taxonomy / post. The taxonomy should exist before the post utilizes it.